# How to render entity when C# HTML decode not working fine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to decode a string that comes from a DB like this:

> All Ablaze &#153; Climbing Rose.

Using either the WebUtility or the HttpUtility `HtmlDecode` method turns the "&#153;" into a Blank instead of a "TM" symbol.

Is there another way to produce the correct output for this type of string?
My Code:
   `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(" All Ablaze &#153; Climbing Rose.")`

Desired output:

> All Ablaze ™ Climbing Rose.

Comment: Share some of the code you have and we will help you get to your desired outcome.

Comment: Probably because its a control character and it means something different in unicode... http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/index.htm vs http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm

Comment: @Chad I have updated the question with the code and output, please note the the & # 153; is separed because the page translate it to the TM, in the DB there are no spaces in between & # 153;

Comment: Place code inside backticks: `&#153;`. But as @Caramiriel said, `&#153;` is not the trademark character, `&#8482;` is.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen how come is not the TM charactaer, as I put &#153; in my question stackoverflows translate it to TM?

Comment: Hmm, you're right, then I am probably completely wrong, ignore me.

Comment: No, it is correct, the fact that Stack Overflow does this is in fact incorrect since these are control characters. They are *ASCII* and *Windows-1252* character codes however but that is not correct. See https://www.webmasterworld.com/forum21/7301.htm

Comment: How do you check the output? By the way, it's a unicode character "control" - http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0099/index.htm

Comment: StackOverflow probably doesn't do this for you, its the browser that converts character sets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

`Html.Raw("All Ablaze &#153; Climbing Rose.")`

Comment: What happens when the book title is `<script>hackThisSite();</script>`?

Comment: Ofc it depends on who inserts the items. I already had this conversation on github. This may only harm client-to-client and will not affect anything on the webserver if it is well secured (server-side). But, I get the point, it may redirect an user to another website or other bad thing.

Comment: But, keep in mind @maxwellb comment. If an outsider is capable of writing a comment you should try another approach.

Comment: @LeandroSoares yes, and rendering HTML as HTML using Html.Raw is correct, as long as you have sanitized it correctly. The intent was to add to the discussion. Since OP has HTML in the DB, it would be somewhat off topic to discuss not putting raw HTML in the DB in the first place. But, if someone else were to store titles, they may wish to Html Decode (as appropriate on ingest if it's tagged as containing HTML), store as unicode, and then Html Encode on the way out.

Comment: @maxwellb, I somewhat agree with you. But i've never faced any problem with raw HTML in the DB :p

Comment: This post *does not* answer the question as asked. The fact @GiovanniRivas accepted it as an answer may that they will fix question to potentially match what they were looking for...

Answer (score 6):

Your issue is that the `&#153;` code is an alt code number and is deprecated. You should be using `&#8482;` instead, which is the Unicode value for the trademark sign. [This](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) is a good reference for reading up on Unicode.

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes "HTML should actually produce a control character" "browsers tend to silently correct that error"

Comment: the thing is I cannot change the data, because the client is the one that manages it :(

Answer (score 1):

Try with [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/7c5fyk1k(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(" All Ablaze &#153; Climbing Rose.")
```

Comment: I have tried this and the output is All Ablaze Climbing Rose. Leaves the TM out, seems that is not able to decode it.